# Use a Javascript variable in C#

Tags: c#, javascript

I want to use a Javascript variable in C#, is it possible, how do I go about it?
Thanks

Comment: Please be more specific. What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: This is a bit like saying I want to read vinyl with a CD player.

Comment: I want to check the value of a JS variable (after some client side validations), after server trip on page load, so that based on that value I can perform some actions.

Comment: @Andreas Zoltan: You probably mean laserdisc player, or have you ever seen a 5" vinyl?

Comment: @takrl - hmmmm - laserdisc + vinyl - I think it's got legs you know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you would be interested in the **value held by the variable** and to make it available to the C# code as you suggest it needs to be posted to the server.

So you can assign the value to a `Hidden` Field which you can retrieve at the server end and use the value

Answer (score 8):

best way is to write that variable to a cookie, and read from C#.

but you can also use:

- send that variable asynchronously
- send that variable as part of a `POST`

Answer (score 1):

Use asp.net hidden field and update the value on client side using JS. Then you can easily access that field on server side since it would be a server control